# Zooming / Resizing Images get blurry

Tags: c#, image, winforms, zooming, picturebox

I’m using WinForms. My application works like a simple image viewer. It opens Image files goes to the next page, zooms in and zooms out. The problem with my application is that when I re-size or zoom in the image, the image starts getting blurry. How do I prevent my images from getting blurry when I’m zooming out or zooming in?

When i view and re-size the same image on Windows Photo Viewer the images is clear. When i open the image in my application the image is clear but as soon as i start re sizing it for example when i start using zoom it starts becoming blurry.

I tried implementing this code in my zoom out method but i didn't couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
  Size newSize = new Size((int)(originalBitmap.Width * zoomFactor), 
  (int)(originalBitmap.Height * zoomFactor));
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(originalBitmap, newSize);
```

The image dimensions i look at:

Dimensions: 2540 x 3289

Dimensions: 2533 x 3284

Dimensions: 2538 x 3282

Dimensions: 2479 x 3508

```
    FileStream _stream;
    Image _myImg; // setting the selected tiff
    string _fileName;
    private int intCurrPage = 0; // defining the current page

    private void Open_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; //Shows the filename in the lable
            Open_Image_Control();

            Image img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
            pictureBox1.Width = img.Width;
            pictureBox1.Height = img.Height;
            this.pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone); // Rotates image 90 degrees

        }
    }

    public void Open_Image_Control()
    {
        Image myBmp;

        if (_myImg == null)
        {
            _fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
            File.Copy(@lblFile.Text, _fileName);
            _stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            _myImg = Image.FromStream(_stream);
        }

        int intPages = _myImg.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page); // getting the number of pages of this tiff
        intPages--; // the first page is 0 so we must correct the number of pages to -1
        lblNumPages.Text = Convert.ToString(intPages); // showing the number of pages
        lblCurrPage.Text = Convert.ToString(intCurrPage); // showing the number of page on which we're on

        _myImg.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, intCurrPage); // going to the selected page

        myBmp = new Bitmap(_myImg, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        pictureBox1.Image = myBmp; // showing the page in the pictureBox1 
    }

    private void ZoomIN_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Width += 175; //Zoom width by 75
        this.pictureBox1.Height += 175; //Zoom height by 75
    }

    private void ZoomOut_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Width -= 175; //Zoom out width by 75
        this.pictureBox1.Height -= 175; //Zoom out height by 75
    }

    private void NextPage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (intCurrPage == Convert.ToInt32(lblNumPages.Text)) // if you have reached the last page it ends here
                                                              // the "-1" should be there for normalizing the number of pages
        { intCurrPage = Convert.ToInt32(lblNumPages.Text); }
        else
        {

            intCurrPage++; //page increment (Goes to next page)
            Open_Image_Control();
            this.pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone); // Rotates image 90 degrees
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Use a higher quality image? What is the source image size?

Comment: The image is high quality. It is crisp and clear when i open it from Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: Part of the issue is that increasing the width/height of a picturebox by a fixed amount is not really "zooming". Your images do not have a square aspect ratio so you can't size them w/h the same physical amount and expect them to keep the aspect ratio. Try multiplying by some number (<1 to zoom out, >1 to zoom in) instead of using a fixed 175 for both w/h.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Simple and functional way to zoom picturebox images with scroll bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270144/c-simple-and-functional-way-to-zoom-picturebox-images-with-scroll-bars)

Comment: Enlarging over the original size will of course make it pixelated. Do not use the 1st method for display and when you actually chnage the pixels always start from the original, not from the last size! What is the PB's sizeMode?

Comment: The `PictureBoxSizeMode` is `StretchImage` . @TaW

Comment: Ouch, that will distort the image. Always use Zoom! And always keep the aspect ratio to avoid empty spaces in the PB! You can add pixels to, say the width, but then have to calculate the new width..!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The picture is looking a little better now.  @TaW