# Why bitmaps images are not displaying correctly in Azure website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, system.drawing

For my azure website (ASP.NET and C#) I am creating a image based on some coordinates, but the problem I'm having is that, once the image is deployed into azure website it is so much thicker that on my localhost website.

I have been reading a lot about this but couldn't come up with a solution. The code that creates the image is the same, I don't make any change before moving the code to azure.

I won't paste the code because it's too large to paste it here. It does and calculates a lot of things.

Any suggestion you could give me?

Comment: What do you mean with thicker and what have you been reading? Please provide some of the urls/articles/... that you read on this subject.

Comment: are you sure you have to same zoom level in your browser for the localhost-website that you have for the Azure website?

Comment: No, how can I check that? I didn't know that was possible

Comment: In most configurations browsers like Chrome keep your zoom level saved on a per-website basis. Strg + scrollwheel in any direction should display your current zoom level for that particular website on the top right (Chrome).

Comment: Guys, Thank you for your help. I found the solution on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915958/how-to-zoom-inout-an-image-in-c-sharp is using the Size to resizre the image