# Zooming image in picturebox centered in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, zooming, picturebox

I have a WinForms picturebox with the Picture Size Mode set to StretchImage. I need the picturebox to zoom in by 1% every two milliseconds which will use a loop.

The pictureBox must zoom in at the center and scrollbars should not be shown.

This is my current code that doesn't work:

```
while (Visible) {
    pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width + 1;
    pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Height + 1;
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
}
```

In this code, there is a window, but the image does not move in any way.
How should this problem be implemented?

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915958/how-to-zoom-inout-an-image-in-c-sharp

Comment: What's the SizeMode?

Comment: StretchImage. Should I set the size to normal and set the default size to the form size?