# Zoom performance in C# Bitmap

Tags: c#, performance, bitmap, scaling, raster

I'm working with C# WinForms app and using custom control for displaying bitmap images. The problem is, when zooming images I'm using `MouseWheel` event and, creating new `Bitmap` image, based on new width and height properties.

On small and average images that works fine, but when size of image is about 3000*3000 pixels or greater, I have serious performance problems in line

```
scaledImage = new Bitmap(baseImage, size);
```

Where size - new `size` of image and `baseImage` - my original .png image.
So, maybe exists some another solution for such scaling?

Also I must mention that I'm limited with .net 3.5

Comment: I'm going to point out that even if this was the best way to scale an image, you shouldn't scale more of the image than you need to display. If you zoom in 100x on a 512x512 image to display on a 1920x1080 screen, you only need a tiny section of the original image to be increased to that size because that's all you can display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zoom in&out an image in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915958/how-to-zoom-inout-an-image-in-c-sharp). Graphics.DrawImage will probably be faster. It also works in 3.5.

Comment: Use the DrawImage overload that takes two Rectangles to display just the right area at just the right scale! This will also give you options on display like smoothing or keeping it crispy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get particular part of image, displaying right now. graphics.DrawImage gives about 5-10% of performance or even less